# Which kind of Conditional is it?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Would you teach me by some more similar examples, please?

> ***If*** a homing pigeon **is to** navigate with its Sun compass, its clock ***must*** be properly set by cues provided by the daylight/darkness cycle.

Can I paraphrase it to the First Conditional as follows without distortion:

> If a homing pigeon navigates with its Sun compass, its clock will be properly set by cues provided by the daylight/darkness cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your paraphrase is consistent with it, but misses something.

A better paraphrase would be "**In order that** a homing pigeon can navigate with its Sun compass, its clock **must**  be ... "

It is expressing a (material not logical) implication: only if the clock is set, can it navigate. Your paraphrase might be taken by a logician to mean this, but in ordinary language it doesn't mean it.

Comment: +1 Note that *be to* implies temporal subsequence: the eventuality in the condition clause falls after the eventuality in the 'consequence' clause. *Be to* might be expressed *be going to*, or the 'consequence' clause might employ the adverb *first*.